# Scoping confusion in Express

Tags: node.js, express

I'm using Express (4.10.8) in a Node-based webserver that is handling multiple sites, using the 'vhost' package. Each domain is in its own directory, and each has its own "app.js" code.

I'm trying to rewrite the request URL (long story) and the code below, inside the app.use() function, behaves as desired.

But outside that function, the commented-out logging call fails with an error that indicates my reference there to req.url is out of scope:

```
ReferenceError: req is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/brianc/websites/rppc/app.js:12:36)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/brianc/websites/app.js:82:15)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
{"level":"error","message":"Forever detected script exited with code: 1"}
```

I'm trying to get my head around what's going on, and also, of course, to fix the issue, as I need the rewritten request URL instead of the one that came in to the server.  The regex works as intended inside the function.

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/../public'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname ));
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
        req.url  = req.url.replace(/(.*)?<!\.html|\.pdf$/, "/$1.pdf");
        req.url =  req.url + ".pdf";
        console.log("URL was changed to: " + req.url);
        next();
});
//console.log("We changed URL to " + req.url);
app.use(express.static(__dirname,{extensions: ['html','pdf']}));

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: I suggest copying and pasting the exact text of any errors you have.  Feel free to redact filenames, urls, or other sensitive info, but don't paraphrase an error like _"an error that indicates my reference there to req.url is out of scope"_

Comment: That's just basic scoping: yes, function arguments are only accessible _inside the function_. The request handlers get called when there's a matching request; when the top-level code runs, that's just the app starting up and _preparing_ to accept requests.

Answer (score 0):

Found my answer!!

In Express v4, one cannot munge the request URL inside the use() method.  But it will work with the get() method.

So this code did what I was trying to do above, i.e. add ".pdf" to any request URL that comes in without any suffix. . .

```
app.get(/^[^.]*$/, (req, res,next) => {
  console.log("No suffix on " + req.url + " \n")
  req.url += ".pdf"
  next()
})
```